# Error while running h2o.init function in R

Tags: r, h2o

While running h2o.init() function I am facing an error as mentioned below, can you please help me understand why am I getting the error and what should in do inorder to avoid this error in future.

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    C:\Users\ransingh.ray\AppData\Local\Temp\abc/h2o_RANSINGH_RAY_started_from_r.out
    C:\Users\ransingh.ray\AppData\Local\Temp\abc/h2o_RANSINGH_RAY_started_from_r.err

java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................Diagnostic HTTP Request:
   HTTP Status Code: -1
HTTP Error Message: Failed to connect to localhost port XXXXX: Connection refused
 
Error Output:
   Only Java 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and 13 are supported, system version is 14.0.1 
Error in h2o.init() : H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
```

Comment: Remove your Java 14 installation and install a lower version Java

Answer (score 5):

It's written on the error line :

> Error Output: Only Java 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and 13 are supported, system
> version is 14.0.1 Error in h2o.init() : H2O failed to start, stopping
> execution.

Only Java 8 up to 13 are supported in your version of H2O, while yours is 14.0.1, which causes it failed to execute.  Java 14 support was [officially added in H2O 3.30.1.1](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html).  You can either downgrade your version of Java, or upgrade your version of H2O.  H2O 3.30.1.1 was recently [released](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html) and not yet on CRAN, but you can install it using the following code in R:

```
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zeno/1/R")
```

Comment: thanks @deja , I tried following the instruction mentioned in the h2o website, h2o 3.30.1.1 is available in http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R. But when i tried to load the h2o after downloading it now, i am getting an error message   : Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘h2o’ in get(method, envir = home):
 lazy-load database 'C:/XXXX/h2o.rdb' is corrupt

Comment: can you please suggest how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

Tried uninstalling the h2o , then stopped the current R session, then restarted the R session and followed the installation process mentioned in h2o website.
This is working now.